# Exception loading C# StringCollection Setting

Tags: c#

In a C# app a client is getting following error

```
The property 'PlayLists' could not be created from it's default value. Error message: Could not load file or assembly '0 bytes loaded from System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

PlayLists is a setting of type StringCollection

the default values in Settings are

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <string>test</string>
</ArrayOfString>
```

The stack trace I got is

```
  at System.Configuration.SettingsPropertyValue.Deserialize()
  at System.Configuration.SettingsPropertyValue.get_PropertyValue()
  at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.GetPropertyValueByName(String propertyName)
  at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.get_Item(String propertyName)
  at System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.GetPropertyValue(String propertyName)
  at System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.get_Item(String propertyName)
  at Sync.Properties.Settings.get_PlayLists() 
  at Sync.FormMain.selectLastSycLists()
  at Sync.FormMain..ctor()
  at Sync.Program.Main()
```

The method in my code that started all this looks like this.

```
    private void selectLastSycLists()
    {
        // Accessing PlayLists caused it
        foreach(String settingsPList in Properties.Settings.Default.PlayLists)
        {               
         ...
        }
    }
```

I am not quite sure what is causing this, 
Any advise would be great

Comment: Repair the .Net framework on that machine.

Comment: @SLaks I am encoding UTF 16 because the Settings might contains unicode characters.. But does it matter ?

Comment: XML is typically UTF8 (which also supports Unicode characters).  Are you sure that the file is actually encoded as UTF-16?

Comment: @SLaks I am actually not sure if file is UTF-16 encoded. It was generated by visual studio and it is deployed as-is. But when I test it on my machine I did not have any problem starting the app

Comment: Since it happens on one clients pc and its complaining about deserializing the value, can we see the value in clients config file, other than the default `test` value

Comment: @SLaks Something I realised as you pointed out I checked the user.config file on my machine at the top user.config file says utf-8.  I tried to reproduce by deleting user.config on my machine and starting the app. Its starts without any exception

Comment: I note the following: Error message: Could not load file or assembly **0 bytes loaded from System** Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'  Why it is trying to load an assembly called "Error message: Could not load file or assembly '0 bytes loaded from System"?  That's not right.  Have a look through the config files on the problem machine for the string "0 bytes loaded from".  I suspect that's where you'll find your problem.